# PHP find a complex keyword (string) in a plain text

Tags: php

this might be a frequent question but my case is:

assuming 
my keyword is "**black pepper**"
and my plain text is a recipe that contains the word "peppercorns"

i would like to be bale to highlight the word **peppercorns**, not just pepper (eventhough this latter could be a good achievemet as well)

is it possible in php using preg_match? shoudl i split the keyword and craeate mutliple comparisons?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is slighly unclear. You want to highlight everything that is connected to black pepper? In the case of peppercorns that's easy because it's in one word together with pepper. But what if the text contains 'blackbirds', would you then highlight this word as well?

What you're trying to do needs intelligence or at least a complex lexical approach, you can't solve it with an algorithm.

If your keyword is only pepper, it becomes much easier, but only if pepper has only one meaning. In that case you could highlight everything that has pepper in it. But you would miss terms using more than one word. Here you would need a lexical approach again. If your engine knows that black pepper and white pepper are sub-patterns of pepper, then it works.

Comment: lets' say i should have a db that contains terms tagged as ingredients, and terms tagged as adjectives, so when i do the matching the words i can select only those terms that are ingredients and exclude the rest...right? kindof?

Comment: actually now i'm thinking better, could be confusing because if i search for pepper i could find also chilli peppers or so and those are not related to black pepper...mmm i think my idea is to hard to achieve at this point...

Answer (score 1):

If you split the keywords and glue them together with carets you can use them as part of a simple regex:

```
$result = preg_replace("/(\w*(?:black|pepper)\w*)/i", "<b>$1</b>", $target_text);
```

EDIT: removed g from the regex flags, remembered it's functionality wrong